# Customising the index.html file?

Tags: swagger-ui

I've been messing around with Spring Boot and was pointed at Swagger as a way of documenting my Rest Api.

I managed to get it working except I can't figure out how to customise the index.html file. Whenever I go to http://localhost:8080/index.html it loads the default pet store search bar one and not the one I customised.

I've gone through a tonne of pages online and tried a hundred things but nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my swagger index.html code I have something that looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
    var pathArray = location.href.split( '/' );
    var protocol = pathArray[0];
    var host = pathArray[2];
    var base = protocol + '//' + host;
    if (url && url.length > 1) {
        url = url[1];
    } else {
        url = base + "/api-docs";
    }
    window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
        url: url,
        ...
```

This loads the base, my json code for my swagger api is at `/api-docs` as you might understand.

Comment: Yeah I've got something like this but where do you put your index.html and when you go to  http://localhost:8080/index.html do you see your customised page or the default one with the search bar? If I input http://localhost:8080/api-docs into the search bar I see my api but I want to see my api by default when I go to http://localhost:8080/index.html if that makes sense?

Comment: You have to modify the index.html to include this code, then it will load your swagger specification.

Comment: Yeah I have customised the index.html e.g I removed its header (<div id='header'>) element etc. I copied the dist folder into my project but it still won't load my index.html. Is there somewhere in my code I should've pointed at my index.html or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's practically impossible for me to know what you are missing, however a first good step would be to see if the code I posted is in your index.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think my problem was not using the @RequestMapping to point at the index.html so it was loading the default one. Going to mess around with that and hopefully that fixes it.